# Rebuild HTTP flow with incubated Java 10 HttpClient

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I'm trying to rebuild the session setup to a web server by a Java HttpClient application. I have chosen the [incubated HttpClient provided with Java 9 and Java 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient.html).

With Chrome I captured this headers from a single request:

```
General
Request URL: https://<some_url>?user_id=1176&onlyDirectUserItems=true&onlyAssignedToUser=true&show=Unresolved&itemsFilter=0
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: <theProxy>:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 164
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 14:33:16 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=300, max=100
Location: https://<another_url>:443/nesp/app/plogin?agAppNa=app_me_company_ext&c=secure/name/password/uri&target=%22https://<another-usr>/browseIssues.spr?user_id=1176&onlyDirectUserItems=true&onlyAssignedToUser=true&show=Unresolved&itemsFilter=0%22
P3p: CP="NOI"
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: IPCZQX03224bfb75=030003000000000000000000000000008f7aed69; path=/; domain=.me.de
Via: 1.1 <host> (Access Gateway-ag-7169149846802036-13837511)

Request Headers
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: org.ditchnet.jsp.tabs.wiki=wiki-wysiwyg; ZNPCQ003-31393000=6c2f99a3; ZNPCQ003-32323200=cd188fdd
DNT: 1
Host: <host>
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters
user_id: 1176
onlyDirectUserItems: true
onlyAssignedToUser: true
show: Unresolved
itemsFilter: 0
```

What can be seen the Response Header provides a URL (header-key: "location") which I need to grab and call next. But with my http client I fail with status-code 400 and get almost nothing

This is my code

```
       url = "https://<some_url>?user_id=1176&onlyDirectUserItems=true&onlyAssignedToUser=true&show=Unresolved&itemsFilter=0";

       HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
               .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("<theProxy>", 8000)))
               .cookieHandler(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL))
               .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.SAME_PROTOCOL)
               .build();

       HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
               .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0")
               .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
//             .header("Host", "<host>")
               .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
               .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
               .header("Accept-Language", "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
               .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
               .uri(new URI(url))
               .build();

       HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());
       HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();
       Map<String, List<String>> headerMap= headers.map();
       for (String key : headerMap.keySet()) {
           System.out.println(">"+key+"<");
           for (String value : headerMap.get(key)) {
               System.out.println("   " + value); 
           }
       }
       System.out.println(response.statusCode());
       System.out.println(response.body());
```

I have no clue what might be wrong and how to proceed to get this done. I hope someone can tell me what to ty next.

What I also do not understand: I had to remove the header "Host" - because I got the response: "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

The very same header as can be found in the Chrome-listing

Comment: @Michael It is only incubated. Java 10: [`jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpClient.html)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was confirming Michael's *"I thought the HttpClient was only incubated"*, to which I said "It is". Previous comment edited to clarify.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: Have now setup Fiddler to capture the requests. When comparing the results, it turns out that the httpclient does not provide the cookies to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it run with Apache HttpClient. I cannot tell what is wrong with the incubated HttpClient - but there is for sure a reason that it is not a fully integrated part of the Java 9/10 delivery